# Trouble passing mongoose variables to pug template through express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I have a User model through Mongoose, and I'm trying to create a simple CRUD API, starting with the Users part, problem is that my "index," and "create" routes seem to be working but the detail page won't seem to accept the variable being passed to it, and I can't render things on the page.

My User schema is very simple for now, just to get the API working (./models/user.js)

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50,
    minlength: 2,
    trim: true
  }
})
```

The controllers for the routes that DO work look like this (./controllers/user_controller.js)

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    res.render('userindex', {users: users})
  })
}

exports.new = function(req, res, next) {
  newUser = new User({ name: req.body.name })
  newUser.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) res.send(err)
    res.redirect('/users')
  })
}

exports.addUser = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('newuser')
}
```

The routes look like this so far (./routes/userRouter.js)
I do recognize that the routes for add and new are reversed, it'll be fixed.

```
userRouter.get('/', userController.index)

userRouter.get('/new', userController.addUser)

userRouter.post('/add', userController.new)

userRouter.get('/:id', userController.detail)
```

The only thing left is the broken controller: (./controllers/user_controller.js)

```
exports.detail = function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({'_id': req.params.id}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) res.send(err)

    res.render('userdetail', {user: user})
  })
}
```

And the template that won't seem to receive the data. (./views/userdetail.pug)

```
p #{user.name}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find returns an array, so there's no user to template. Either template the first item on the collection:

```
res.render('userdetail', {user: user[0]})
```

or use .findOne instead.